# Copy Paste a row in a asp:GridView using C# in a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So I have a web application that uses a GridView.
We currently add 1 new blank record at a time fill it in and move on. There are times when the data needing to be entered has several fields that need to be duplicated. Is there a way to add a blank row, fill it in , and then copy that row and paste it back into the GridView?

I've looked at clone, but i haven't seen anything that works in a web application. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: are you adding the row on the server, or on the client? There are a lot of ways to use a GridView and a lot of ways to add a row. You just need to set the initial values on the new row.

Comment: Currently I add the blank row to the sqlserver, then fill it in and update the GV as well as the sql server. After the row is updated, I'd like to be able to copy the row and insert it to the server , going back to update the necessary fields.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way, is you could add a copy button to the grid?

Say we have this grid:

```
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
            cssclass="table table-hover borderhide">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="First Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Text = '<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Last Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server" Text = '<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="City">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Text = '<%# Eval("City") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Active">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="Active" runat="server" Checked = '<%# Eval("Active") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Copy">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdCopy" runat="server" Text="Copy"
                            ImageUrl="~/Content/copy1600.png" Height="32px" Width="32px" 
                            OnClick="cmdCopy_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn-primary" OnClick="cmdSave_Click1" />

            <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Row" CssClass="btn-primary" style="margin-left:20px" OnClick="cmdAdd_Click1"/>
            <br />
```

So, code to load this grid up

```
    private DataTable rstPeople = new DataTable();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadGrid();
        ViewState["MyTable"] = rstPeople;
    }
    else
        rstPeople = (DataTable)ViewState["MyTable"];

    }
    public void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from People", 
                                    new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();

            rstPeople.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());

            GridView1.DataSource = rstPeople;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

And the add row button code:

```
   protected void cmdAdd_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GridToTable();      // user may have edits
        // add a new row to the grid

        DataRow OneRow = rstPeople.NewRow();
        OneRow["Age"] = 0;
        OneRow["Active"] = true;
        rstPeople.Rows.Add(OneRow);
        GridView1.DataSource = rstPeople;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

So we click on add row, and that gives us this:

[image]

So, we have that blank row. But, in place of add row, we could click the copy button, and that would add a row - but copy from current. (I suppose we could have a copy + paste button - but that's WAY TOO much UI here).

So, add row = add blank row.

but, copy row button - add row - copy.

The code for that looks like this:

```
   protected void cmdCopy_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        GridToTable();      // user might have done some editing

        ImageButton cmdCopy = (ImageButton)sender;
        GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)cmdCopy.Parent.Parent;

        DataRow CopyFrom = rstPeople.Rows[gvRow.RowIndex];

        DataRow OneRow = rstPeople.NewRow();
        OneRow["Age"] = 0;
        OneRow["FirstName"] = CopyFrom["FirstName"];
        OneRow["LastName"] = CopyFrom["LastName"];
        OneRow["City"] = CopyFrom["City"];
        OneRow["Active"] = CopyFrom["Active"];

        rstPeople.Rows.Add(OneRow);
        GridView1.DataSource = rstPeople;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

Now I not shared how teh save button works.

So, the user now can add new rows. Tab around - edit any row. or even copy a new row (and again, edit some more).

So save the whole mess and grid back to the database, we

```
 Send Grid back to table
 Send table back to database.
```

So the save all button is thus this:

```
   protected void cmdSave_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        GridToTable();

        // now send table back to database with updates
        string strSQL = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, City, Active from People WHERE ID = 0";

        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, 
                                    new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter daupdate = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
            SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuild = new SqlCommandBuilder(daupdate);

            daupdate.Update(rstPeople);
        }
    }
```

again, really simple. And note how we did not bother with templates etc. (too messy, and really not less code then above).

I suppose you could have for a new row a "paste" icon, but if the users going to have to pick a row and copy - might as well make it "add row + copy" in one operation.

(and it not really a copy button, but more of a "duplicate row" button.

Only routine not posted was the GridToTable. This works, since we always persist the table, but any edits in GV have to be send back to the table, and thus we use this:

```
   void GridToTable()
    {
        // pull grid rows back to table.
        foreach (GridViewRow rRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            int RecordPtr = rRow.RowIndex;
            DataRow OneDataRow;
            OneDataRow = rstPeople.Rows[RecordPtr];
            OneDataRow["FirstName"] = ((TextBox)rRow.FindControl("txtFirst")).Text;
            OneDataRow["LastName"] = ((TextBox)rRow.FindControl("txtLast")).Text;
            OneDataRow["City"] = ((TextBox)rRow.FindControl("txtCity")).Text;
            OneDataRow["Active"] = ((CheckBox)rRow.FindControl("Active")).Checked;
        }
    }
```

As noted I suppose you could drop in a "copy" button, and ONLY persist + save the row index, and then have a paste button - this would allow a cut + paste between any rows, and not be limited to just new rows. (but, that would allow the user quite easy to over-write a existing row - again UI overload from user training point of view.

The above trick is quite slick, since any new rows, any edits are sent back to the database in one simple Update operation. (and the provider is smart - if a row was not touched or changed, then sql update statements are not generated.

This whole trick works due to persisting the table in ViewState. Be warned, if you have a datapager, then you would have to call GridToTable in such navigation, or in fact execute a save command.

Also note how we picked up the .parent.parent (grid row) and again did not bother with teh GV event model. And without a gazilion template stuff, we also saved world poverty in terms of not having to mess with mutiple templates.

In fact, for any grid beyond the above, I use the exact same above approch, but perfer a ListView. The reason is that you can just drag + drop in standard asp.net controls, and you don't have to needless surround them with "item template" which again is too much work and effort.

Comment: Whooaa...thats a lot. Let me digest and reply tomorrow. Thanks for your effort. Much appreciated!! Would it generally be the same for bound fields in my gridview? Thanks

Comment: Sure, in my sample the rows are databound. But I don't use extra templates for editing, or adding, since we really don't need them. But, if you look close, I used templated columns, but if you use boundfields, then we use .cells[] collection in place of FindControl - the code would be much the same, but without find controls. I suppose we also could go all out, and add a JavaScript right click to copy - that is possible, but this was simple server side code - so clean and easy. --- only real difference is .cells[] collection is by column number - not the name, but everything else is same.

Comment: Having a tough time copying the selected row. I see you mention it should be by number, but how id it grabbed?

Comment: Take a close look at the button I dropped into the grid. Look close at the button stub event above called cmdCopy_Click. It first copies the grid back to the table (if you allow grid edits). It then gets/grabs the row you clicked on with cmdCopy.Parent.Parent. That is the row the user clicked on. From that row, I then get the row index, and then simple add a new row, copy values from that grid row, and then re-bind the grid to display this new row we just added. So cmdCopy.Parent.Parent is how that click button event get the current grid row (I cast it to GridViewRow).

Comment: Once I have the whole grid row, then I can copy values from that grid row to the new row. However SINCE I have the table persisted, then I just grab the row index to the EXISTING TABLE that I am keeping updated. So, I use the values from that table row for setting the values I use for the new row I add. Set the values, add new row to the data table, and then re-bind grid to show this new row.  So, I really don't have to get/grab the values from the grid row, since that grid row gets me the index row into the table. I could however copy from the grid if I had not have a persisted table.

Comment: so we add rows to the table, not the grid. We can add 2 or 5 new rows to that table. However, editing that table, and changing values, or EVEN adding rows to the table do not go back to database until we hit save button. So we don't add rows to the database, but only that in memory table. When we hit submit button (save), then we send the table with edits, with new rows back to the database in one operation.  So to save grid edits? We send grid back to the table, and then send the table back to the database. This also means we can have a un-do button, even for added rows by just re-load table

Comment: Ok, I identify the the row index a little differently. Do I need to add to the table or can I just do an insert to the grid?

Comment: If final goal is to send edits + changes + deletes + add rows back to the database? Then using the table to drive "everything" will save BOATLOADS of work and code. And if you add row direct to grid, then which are new, and old and which to send back to database? Far more easy to just add row to table, and then send table back to grid.  Note how I don't' even need edit templates or nothing for this setup, and we have full update of edits in one simple easy operation. And a un-do button could be added - just re-load using loadgrid.  So, 1-2 lines code to add a new row to table is far less work.

Comment: So seems like the table is teh way to go. I do not have a table yet, I'll plan to add that tomorrow. Thanks. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: Good luck - I mean, that data has to come from some place? So, fill the table, bind to grid and you get the display. I think it quite hard to fill out a grid without some table first. Even using SELECT * FROM myTable where ID = 0 is a great start, since then you get the correct table structure without much code.

Comment: I currently put the data in my gridview with out a table....am I doing something wrong? Or just different?

Comment: Not really, but the real question is what you want to do after you put data in that grid? You most likely want to eventually save the data, and thus we back to a table for that ultimate goal. so, by starting out with a table, we with ease can achieve the last goal in mind. Look at the code for the above example - note how easy it is to add a row of data. And note how the whole data save is sending the one table with edits to the database. And what happens if you need to display existing data? Now the same design and work and efforts can be 100% re-used for that goal.

Comment: So I currently do a pull from the database and load the grid. Then when needed I have an ADD button that adds (inserts) a new blank row to the database and refreshes the grid at the same time showing the new blank row. What I wanted to do was add a check box (done) use the findcontrol on that row, and then copy that row into the db and refresh the grid to display the newly copied row. Does that change anything with using a table? Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I add to the table - but we not yet sent that back to the database. And thus the user can still bail out, not add the row, right? I might add a few rows, and then decide I don't want to save that work. I mean, you can add a row to the database, then you have to allow edits, and then update again? (how much code you want to write here?).  I don't add the row to the database, just to the table. That way they can now edit that new row and THEN save. It is at save time we add the new rows. What you going to do if user hits add, and then decides they don't want that row?

Comment: got it, so it's just a temp table while users are copying data.

Comment: Yes, but that temp table is also used to fill the grid, and edits are in that temp table. And more specific, we load that datatable from the server, but from that point on, we using that data table in memory for edits, additions, and even deletes. When we are ready to save those changes, then as noted we can do this in one simple update operation. That update operation handles edits, adds, and even deletes. So I not really sure i would call it a temp table, but a better term is disconnected table. As noted the advantage is not only a single save button, but also allows for a undo button.